# How to Check & Get Balance of ANY Ethereum address

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I already know how to retrieve the ether balance of MY account with the below command.

`web3.eth.getBalance(MY_ADDRESS).`

But, I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the ether balance of ANY account.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the balance of any account?

Any references or help will be thankful.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `web3.eth.getBalance('0x2910543af39aba0cd09dbb2d50200b3e800a63d2')` for example.
For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312884/how-do-i-get-the-balance-of-an-account-in-ethereum

Comment: It works even if the address is not within my Ethereum node (Geth)? because I attach the Geth JavaScript Console and use eth.getBalance('ANY ETHER ADDRESS') and it does not return the balance correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "not within my Ethereum node". Your node should connect to the network and get the latest state of the blockchain. Balances should also be updated accordingly. My guess is that your node is not up to date, but impossible to say with this information.

Comment: If you are running against a locally running node and trying to get historical balances, that node will have to be running as an archive node, otherwise it will return zero balance. Non archive nodes return current balances but not historical balances. In fact, that’s the difference.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen 
I have a remote server that is running Geth, and it is synchronizing up to the latest state of the blockchain. If I use eth.getBalance() to look up how many Ethereum an address has (any addresses of any blocks I find in Etherscan) in JavaScript Console, it returns 0.

Comment: @Thomas Jay Rush
I am not sure what you mean by non archive nodes. How can I make my node "non archive node"?

Comment: With Parity, it's `parity --pruning archive`. I don't know how to start a geth node in archive mode (or if it's even called archive mode). On my Linux box it takes up about 800GB, so be warned.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush 800GB? that's too much data. I might as well use [Infura](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/infura.html#signing-up) service. But, as I am not too sure if Infura service is trustworthy.

Comment: I’m not sure Infura even runs archive nodes. I’d be interested to learn. Please post here if you find out.